# phantom capture https webpage

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I use phantomjs to capture a https webpage, but the resulting image is a whole black image. How do I fix it or does it mean phantomjs can't capture an https webpage?

code like this:

```
var webpage = require('webpage');
var page = webpage.create();

page.open('https://twitter.com/JavaScriptDaily',function(status){    
    page.render('twitter.jpeg', {format: 'jpeg', quality: '100'});   
    phantom.exit();
});
```

Comment: @ArtjomB. this is from phantomjs document    http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/render.html

Comment: Ok, your script works for me. I'm using version 1.9.7 on windows. Have you tried updating?

Comment: Also works on linux/armhf with 1.9.7 without any further commandline parameters or options.

Comment: @ArtjomB. not for me, it's weird...

Comment: Have you tried `--ignore-ssl-errors=true` or `--web-security=false`? Is this only a problem with jpeg or are png and pdf also affected? You could look for errors with `--debug=yes`.

Answer (score 0):

Render your image in png, it will solve your problem.

```
var webpage = require('webpage');
var page = webpage.create();

page.open('https://twitter.com/JavaScriptDaily',function(status){    
    page.render('twitter.png', {format: 'png'});   
    phantom.exit();
});
```