# PhantomJS returns black screenshot when is started from Jersey rest service

Tags: java, jersey, tomcat7, phantomjs, jersey-2.0

When I start `service.snapshot(msg);` not from Jersey Resource then it works ok. But for this code below, it generates blank png/pdf file.

```
@GET
@Path("/snapshot")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public RequestResponse snapshot( @QueryParam("url") String url,  // snapshot(...)
                                 @QueryParam("format") String format,
                                 @QueryParam("quality") int quality) throws InterruptedException {

    final PageSnapshotMsg msg = new PageSnapshotMsg.Builder().url(url).
                                                              format(format).
                                                              quality(quality).
                                                              build();

    return service.snapshot(msg);
}
```

The PhatomJS js-script which is generated is the same:
I wonder what it could be?

**UPDATE:**
I tried to make my PhantomJS script look like this (added delay **2000**), but it did not help:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.viewportSize = { width: 800, height: 600 };
page.open('bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063550', function(status) {just_wait(); });

    function just_wait() {
     setTimeout(function() page.render('c:/snapshots_db/1406931931354_bl_ocks_org_mbostock_4063550.png', {format: 'png', quality: '10'});
phantom.exit();}, 2000);}
```

Comment: Also, in your edit you forgot `http://` in the url to open. This is necessary.

Comment: @ArtjomB.That's exactly the reason. missed 'http://'. Whatever wrong url I pass, PhatnomJs returns 0 (success code), I expected something else if url is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL that you `open` needs to be a proper URL. It has to begin with `http://` or `https://`. Otherwise nothing happens.

You should check the `status` argument for a hint.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.open('http://example.com/', function(status){    
    console.log(1, status); // success
    page.open('example.com/', function(status){    
        console.log(2, status); // fail
        phantom.exit();
    });
});
```

Comment: I guess I should use this example to build exit-code: http://phantomjs.org/api/phantom/method/exit.html  (passing code as a parameter to phantom.exit() function)

Comment: @ses You can only return exit codes. So only integers work. Depending on how you invoke it, you can also write something to the console and read it from java, possibly even encode and decode JSON.

Comment: For now I decided to check whether url exists or not from java rather than launching/rely on phantomjs-process/script (since it's time costly). If url does not exist then no need to launch phantomjs process. But that's already details..

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a delay after which the screenshot is to be taken. Just before the  page.render() That helps with the page to actually load before it is rendered. Helped me once. If there is any hope there, do post.

Otherwise, the try checking for write permissions to the directory where the image is being saved (for the application) and if the page url is available..

Might be related.. [Phantomjs creating black output from SVG using page.render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24078368/phantomjs-creating-black-output-from-svg-using-page-render?rq=1)

Please also check for additional related topics..

Comment: I've added delay. Did not help so far (see update). And I'm not trying to show png/svg in chrome, but just letting PhantomJs store images into the folder. And it works but not from tomcat/jersey.